# How check if user authenticated first time with firebase google provider before he sign up

Tags: firebase-authentication

I need check if user authenticated first time with firebase google provider. I can't use (additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) property for checking that, as at that time user has already signed up.
Тhanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly does that mean to you - "if user authenticated first time with firebase google provider"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail the situation you're trying to detect.

Comment: i am making  authentication for a website. Before the user sign up i have additional step as asking the user birthday.  When the user clicks on sign up / sign in, i need to know if that user, with current google account, has already account in my firebase, if he dose i won't ask for the user birthday. I need information about his account, before user automatically sign up. Because, now when the user clicks, he is signed in or signed up automatically. P.S sorry for my English

Comment: It seems like you should just store the birthday in a database, and query it when the user signs in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a user is already signed up with Firebase, the closest you can get is by getting the providers for the user's email address ([Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)), [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail:completion:), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#fetchsigninmethodsforemail)). You'll then have to check if you get the Google provider back.

But this is a somewhat unusual way to use this API, so you might want to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Frank! thank you for answer. Really the problem was in my question not in the firebase) eventually i reached what i need)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Mika. Without knowing what the problem was, it leaves this question in a bit of a limbo though. Can you post your solution as an answer, so that future users can benefit from what you learnt?